# Sending canvas object with restfull api in django

Tags: json, django, pdf, canvas, django-rest-framework

I am using *django* as my backend and I am using restful api to communicate with *react js* frontend. I have created a pdf invoice with **canvas** and I was able to send it via mail system of django. But I also want to show the pdf on *web page*. So I need to send it to front end via *api url*. I tried to send it as response but I got the error:
**Object of type Canvas is not JSON serializable**

The code that I wrote to send pdf:
**return Response(c, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)**

c stands for the canvas object which is a pdf

Is there a solution of this? Or how do I send the pdf to the front end.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can send the static url(eg. 127:.0.0.1:8000/static/yourfile.pdf) for the pdf, which will be rendered by the browser. And you can add a button  in your react frontend which will redirect to the pdf url.

Comment: I create pdf's when they call the url. So pdf files are not located inside the project they are created when they are requested. Do you think it would be possible

Comment: if you want to create pdf in python,  create pdf on the go, you just use pyPDF and save in a static folders of your django app and just give the url for it and delete it afterwards. Else option 2 is to create pdf with javascript, you can send all precomputed data from django in a json response, and than put it into pdf in javascript. i guess there is no way to send a serialize a pdf object as you are trying to do above.  you can use this thread to generate pdf with js or there are libraries available in react.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript

Comment: that worked thank you! I have a last minor problem. When I design a pdf and save it as canvas.save() it saves it inside the project folder. How can I address it to static folder.
I use"from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas" and when I type canvas_object.save() it saves it into project folder

Comment: i guess you just have to overwrite the destination path for generated pdf to url/static/name.pdf,
 acc to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485353/python-reportlab-save-with-canvas-to-specified-location
 you just have to give the path for desired location. in this case, path would be to the static folder. i recommend you to generate path using os.path.
canvas_object.save('./project/..../static/name.pdf',size='letter')